# Overlap a new Div created with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlap

So... it's kind of like the same problem before.  I want it to create a new div when a key is pressed.  It does create it, but it puts it off the background.

```
function attack() {
    $("body").append("<div class='proj'></div>");
    $(".proj").css("position", "absolute");
    $(".proj").css("width", "32px");
    $(".proj").css("height", "32px");
    $(".proj").css("background-color", "#00FFFF");
    $(".proj").css("left", playerPositionLeft);
    $(".prok").css("top", playerPositionTop);
    $(".proj").css("z-index", "2");
}
```

[image]

The Cyan box is the .proj but I need it to be at the red square's location.

Hope you can help!

Comment: one of the selectors is .`prok` is this a typo? playerPositionLeft is `var playerPositionLeft = $('.red').position().left`?

Comment: What's the HTML look like for this? The map overall is a background of the body?

Comment: And is there a different class for the red vs. cyan boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't append the `<div class='proj'></div>` in your `body`. append it in your `div` that is containing the big image. And please remember to add `position:relative` to that `div`